# How to upload file using Selenium when the file input is hidden?

Tags: jquery, selenium, file-upload

I'm trying to automate file upload on a modern web page that uses some fancy drag&drop upload panel on top of the old `<input type="file">`. The element is still on the page but Selenium can't use it - I get the famous

```
"Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"
```

error. I think I've got two options:

1. Make the element somehow visible - but calling `jQuery(...).show()` on it doesn't help, I'm not quite sure why F12 tools report the element as visible but Selenium still thinks it isn't (and, truth to be told, I can't see the file field either, F12 tools just highlight a rectangular area on the page)
2. Set the value of `<input type="file">` via JavaScript but I get all sorts of security errors (tried Firefox and Chrome).

What can I do about it? Ideally, there would be a way to force Selenium to carry out the action no matter if the element is visible or not but I don't think it's possible, is it?

Comment: As my knowledge, if selenium said it's invisible, mean it's invisible with current indicator. You could switch to a more specific indicator to ensure you point to a visible element. I suggest you should waitUntilelementExist, then perform upload file

Comment: The file upload element never becomes visible on this page - it just some kind of fallback or I don't know but by default, it is overlayed by the modern, AJAX-y uploader.

Answer (score 0):

Use an alternative method to hide the file input, such as:

- absolute positioning offscreen
- absolute positioning + clip:rect

then it will work.

**References**

- [How to hide text field in Html File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034826/1113772#8717716)
- [In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/1113772)
- [Blueimp File Upload nothing happening in IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252114/1113772)
- [file input javascript click generated not from a real mouse click chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223150/1113772)

Comment: I do not really control how the page is constructed. Ideally I would be able to call `$selenium->byId('file-input')->forceClick()` or something like that.

Comment: @borek There's another tool called [Sikuli](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014) and a demo project called [Sikuli on Selenium](https://github.com/mubbashir/Sikuli-on-Selenium) which does something like this.